# karma state go could not resolve "..."

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a function in my controller and just test to see if `$state.go` was called.  I put a spy on `$state.go` but when I call the function I get "Could not resolve 'thestate' from state ..."

Here is my controller's function:

```
function cancel(){
  $state.go('thestate', {}, {reload: true});
}
```

and my test:

```
it('should change state to thestate', function() {
  this.scope.cancel();
});
```

when it runs the cancel function I get an error of "Could not resolve 'thestate' from state ..." but I do have a defined state in my routes.

How can I mock states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it is UI Router that is tested in unit test, `ui.router` module doesn't have to be loaded and `$state` has to be mocked, as well as any other service that is not tested in current spec.

```
beforeEach(module('app', { $state: {
  go: jasmine.createSpy()
}));

...

it('...', inject(function ($state) {
  this.scope.cancel();
  expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('thestate', {}, {reload: true});
}));
```